# Using Jquery and Bootstrap with Es6 Import for React App

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Hello I am trying to include jquery and bootstrap into a Reactjs project, but I am using es6 imports to do so. I've included the imports as shown below in my index.js file. But upon page load it gives error saying that Bootstrap's Javascript requires jquery. I've already npm installed all the required packages. How can I get jquery into my bundled and minified final script file?

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found the answer on this site [here](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/696)

**Step 1:** Install both jquery and bootstrap

```
npm install jquery bootstrap --save
```

**Step 2:** Import them in vendor.ts:

```
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
```

**Step 3:** Go to wepback.common.js in config directory and add this inside plugin section:

```
plugins:[
    .....
    ..... ,
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({   
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery'
    })
]
```

This will let bootstrap to find jquery

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551366/what-is-the-defined-execution-order-of-es6-imports) you can not depend on ES6 respecting the order of your `import` statements

Comment: ty for the important info @David !

Comment: @david I am creating a new project using CLI create-react-app. Can you tell how and where to import in it? There is no config directory in the project created by create-react-app.

Comment: If you want to use this with create-react-app either set jquery on the window object yourself (like the next answer suggests) or `npm run/yarn eject` and then you'll find webpack config files under `config/` where you can add these dependencies

Comment: `import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';` its worked for me

Answer (score 2):

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

You can use [Gulp and webpack](https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-gulp.html) to minify your files

Comment: Not looking to use a different importer. I'm currently using es6 imports, webpack, and babel for bundling minification. And I'd like to keep it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Testing with this

```
import jquery from 'jquery'

window.jQuery = jquery

require('bootstrap')
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason jquery needs to be defined in **lowercase** too

```
import jQuery from 'jquery'
global.jQuery = jQuery
global.jquery = jQuery // jquery lowercase  was the solution
global.$ = jQuery
let Bootstrap = require('bootstrap')
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
```

Answer (score 1):

After import all style css file add the below code in your index.js file

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');
require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

***For me it's work in this way***

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
require('jquery')
require('bootstrap')
```

> *my react version is 17.0.2*