# Why IE 11 display blank page rendering react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, polyfills, react-rendering

I have an issue with IE 11 and my react app. I use Webpack, babel and polyfill.io cdn and all is nice until rendering bundeled file, then it stops doing anything.
Do you have any idea what may go wrong?

Comment: All I had to do was to install the `core-js` npm package then add`core-js/stable` to the webpack config's `entry` array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55967048/

Comment: Are you using es6? Because classes (in javascript) are not supported in IE 11 (https://caniuse.com/?search=class)

Answer (score 46):

React is not compatible right away with IE,

From the official documentation :

React supports all popular browsers, including Internet Explorer 9 and above, although some polyfills are required for older browsers such as IE 9 and IE 10.

> We don’t support older browsers that don’t support ES5 methods, but
>   you may find that your apps do work in older browsers if polyfills
>   such as es5-shim and es5-sham are included in the page. You’re on your
>   own if you choose to take this path.

---

To make your application work on IE (11 or 9) you will have to install React-app-polyfill :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-polyfill

Features :

Each polyfill ensures the following language features are present:

```
Promise (for async / await support)
window.fetch (a Promise-based way to make web requests in the browser)
Object.assign (a helper required for Object Spread, i.e. { ...a, ...b })
Symbol (a built-in object used by for...of syntax and friends)
Array.from (a built-in static method used by array spread, i.e. [...arr])
```

Usage

First, install the package using Yarn or npm:

```
npm install react-app-polyfill
```

Now, you can import the entry point for the minimal version you intend to support. For example, if you import the IE9 entry point, this will include IE10 and IE11 support.

Internet Explorer 9

```
// This must be the first line in src/index.js
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9';

// ...
```

Internet Explorer 11

```
// This must be the first line in src/index.js
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';

// ...
```

---

You can also configure your manifest to handle different browsers, using the following doc : https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist

example :

```
"browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "ie >= 9"
]
```

---

More information from the [official site](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/supported-browsers-features/)

Comment: now I'm getting SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'find' of undefined or null reference, have any idea why?

Comment: Array.find() doesn't seem to be compatible with IE at all : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Browser_compatibility

I don't know if babel can do anything about that

Comment: Getting the same error but this solution not works for me.

Comment: @Treycos Any suggestion ? This solution not works for me

Comment: Can you answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57435567/springboot-react-application-not-working-in-internet-explorer-11-and-9

Comment: I did it all but no resolution; to resolve, had to remove es6 arrow function from my functional component and the page loaded (note that this functional component was the first component which was rendered on the page)

Comment: Why should this line be the first one in `index.js`? As imports are done asynchronously according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35552247/4936168

Answer (score 14):

The package react-app-polyfill will help to work react app in ie9 & ie11. This will work both in development and production environment.

Please follow the steps
 1. Edit the index.js file and add the following lines at the very top of the file.

```
    import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9';
    import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
    import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
```

2. Edit the Package.json file and add "ie 11" in the development sections of the browserslist. The default prouduction list is quite generous and does include ie 11 already via the >0.2%

   ```
   "browserslist": {
   "production": [
     ">0.2%",
     "not dead",
     "not op_mini all"
   ],
   "development": [
     "last 1 chrome version",
     "last 1 firefox version",
     "last 1 safari version",
     "ie 11"
   ]
   ```

   }
3. delete your entire node_modules folder
4. run npm install to re-install the node_modules
5. run npm start to run again

Answer (score 13):

For anybody else who stumbles upon this problem,

If react-app-polyfill doesn't work for you, try core-js instead.

```
$ npm install core-js
```

Make sure this is the first line in your src/index.js file:

```
import 'core-js/stable'
```

Also you might not see the fix when you are in development.

For me the issue was solved only in the production version (react build)

Answer (score 8):

`react-app-polyfills` works for me only in production, not in dev. Build, deploy and then test it.

Comment: for me it works only in local (npm start) but in deployment (npm run build) it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Object.assign() in your reducer (for example) or some other functions that IE11 doesn't support without polyfilling you would have this problem.

Comment: I have a polyfill, it seems like the problem causes export const

Comment: Can u answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57435567/springboot-react-application-not-working-in-internet-explorer-11-and-9

Answer (score 2):

I tried the solutions offered above but still couldn't get the page to work on IE11 nor in my old iOS 9.3.2...

I did exactly as suggested by `@Treycos` and `@Kurisubo` but no resolution; to resolve, had to replace es6 arrow function from my functional component into old school declarative style and the page loaded on IE 11 and iOS 9.3.2

**NOTE**: this functional component was the first component which was rendered on the page

Adding this here so that someone can benefit in the future.

Comment: Akber, YOU ARE A LEGEND! This was exactly the problem I was having. You really helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For those who have attempted to use the 'react-app-polyfill/xxx' and were unsuccessful.

First:  Make sure to import those in your 'index.js' file (the file with 'ReactDOM.render(<React.StrictMode>...)'.

Second: Make sure you import it at the top of your code. Above the "import React from 'react'."

Answer (score -1):

Not any polyfill on earth seemed to help so I debugged for ages and finally figured out from a React developer "error" (only seen in IE11 dev. tools):

```
The above error occurred in the <h2> component:
in h2 (created by CMSHeading)
// ...
```

Which had:

```
const {
  ...styles
} = this.props;
return (<h2 styles={styles}>...</h2>);
```

The only thing was that I was accidentally sending other stuff down that wasn't just css styles but Objects etc. So I made sure that I was only sending real styles to it and then everything started working again :)