# Local react Development Version shows blank page in IE

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, polyfills, babel-polyfill

After upgrading to webpack 4 and latest react version . When i open react js development version on IE it shows blank page and shows following error in console.

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
File: 0-9c5f892beeb9f5dfc76b.chunk.js, Line: 2891, Column: 34
```

and above line mentioned below code :

```
"use strict";
/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(module) {
const colorConvert = __webpack_require__(/*! color-convert */ "./node_modules/color-convert/index.js");

const wrapAnsi16 = (fn, offset) => function () {
    const code = fn.apply(colorConvert, arguments);
    return `\u001B[${code + offset}m`;
};
```

I have tried below solutions but nothings works for me :

https://reactjs.org/docs/javascript-environment-requirements.html

[Why IE 11 display blank page rendering react app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53631949/why-ie-11-display-blank-page-rendering-react-app)

Comment: That looks like `node_modules` is not being transpiled via `babel`

Comment: @pete but all modules are compiling  other that this color-convert and ansi-styles

Comment: Most packages from `node_modules` don't need transpilation, but there are some exceptions. You could also ask the `color-convert` authors to publish an ES5 build

Comment: @pete is there any work around for this even i have manually mentioned this while compiling

Comment: Is `node_modules` excluded under the `babel-loader` rule in webpack config? If yes change that exclude rule to something like `node_modules/(?!color-convert)`

Comment: @pete No it's not excluded

Comment: @pete I have provided presets with rules then it gets complied in IE 11 but not in IE10 and IE 9 getting Map is undefined then i have used  
https://reactjs.org/docs/javascript-environment-requirements.html but not works any suggestions regarding this.

Comment: Hm, I would have thought importing `core-js/es6/map` would take care of that. What is the stacktrace?