# How do I support IE 11 with Create React App 3.0?

Tags: internet-explorer, create-react-app

With the release of Create React App 3.0 and the addition of browserlist, adding support for IE 11 is trivial, but the steps can be hard to find if you don't know where to look. The documentation lists "Supported Browsers" and shows the default browserslist configuration ( https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/supported-browsers-features ) but that isn't all you need to know.

Checking browserl.ist with the production settings you'll see IE 11 has greater usage than Edge still ( https://browserl.ist/?q=%3E0.2%25%2C+not+dead%2C+not+op_mini+all ) With a default CRA 3 app you'll get Syntax Error in main.chunk.js and other errors in your app with IE 11.

Comment: eject your app...starts working at that point. then you could have more fine grained control over the webpack.config.js logic

Comment: While this may be "correct" it doesn't help those who want to stay using CRA 3.0 as the question states.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

To stop the errors and get a default create-react-app React application working in IE 11:

1. Create your basic application with `npx create-react-app [AppName]`
2. Add `import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';` to the VERY top of index.js
3. If you need common standard functions like Array.find() that are not supported in IE 11 add `import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';` just below the first line in index.js
4. In package.json copy the production browserlist to development so you can test in IE11 and all other browsers that will work in production
5. Delete the node_modules/.cache directory

Comment: #4. To support ie-11 test environment, just add `"ie 11"` at the end of both production and development, browserlist section into package.json @Naidim

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work when using `npm start` to run the app in dev mode.

Comment: @Graham https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8084#issuecomment-562981098

Comment: @el-duderino Thank you! That fixed it.

Comment: Adding `import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';` to my index.js added 0.5MB to my app! That's a lot.

Comment: Thanks @el-duderino, your recommendation worked, but this fix https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8116 made it so that we no longer need to manually update `node_modules`. Weirdly enough, when I `yarn install`, I don't see a fixed version with `slashes: true` (see the link to merged PR) in the `node_modules/react-dev-utils`, but when I `npm install`, I see a fix with `slashes: true`, even though it installs the same version of `react-dev-utils` as yarn. (I checked `yarn.lock` and `package-lock.json` for `react-dev-utils` versions)

Comment: In addition to the steps above, I had to add `import 'core-js/stable/symbol'` to my `src/index.js` file in order for IE11 to work with a CRA app (CRA=v4.0.1, React=v17.0.1). I put it after the `react-app-polyfill` lines. For some reason, `yarn eject` also worked (without importing of the Symbol polyfill).

Answer (score 7):

IE 11 is a nightmare. There are some things that will probably solve the problem:

1. With `react-app-polyfill` you may update the main things which is a great point to start. The documentation is very straight forward to implement: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-app-polyfill.
2. You are probably also using arrow functions so you'll also need babel to update that for you. The `babel-plugin-transform-arrow-functions` is your best solution for this. It is very nicely explained in the documentation: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-arrow-functions.
3. Check that the app is giving support to most of the browsers in `browserslist`.

Answer (score 4):

If you came here with immer (redux reducers states) issues:

yarn add (or npm install) react-app-polyfill fast-text-encoding

- src/index.js

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
import 'fast-text-encoding/text';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

In your reducer files:

- reducer.js

```
import { enableES5 } from 'immer';

enableES5();//before any logic

/** YOUR LOGIC **/
```

Finally, in `package.json` include `ie 11` in the `browsersList` section for development. (in case)

```
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "ie 11",
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
```