# Running React app on Internet explorer 11 results in stackoverflow

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, create-react-app

I am trying to run my react app on internet explorer 11.

I am using Create-React-App and did everything the docs say -

Added in index.js

```
import "react-app-polyfill/ie11";
import "react-app-polyfill/stable";
import "fast-text-encoding/text"; //this is to bypass the arrow functions syntax errors//
```

In package.json

```
"development": [
  "ie 9",
  "ie 11",
  "last 1 chrome version",
  "last 1 firefox version",
  "last 1 safari version"
]
```

Now, there are no syntax errors but it says

```
SCRIPT28: Out of stack space
0.chunk.js (174412,21)
SCRIPT2343: Stack overflow at line: 174412
```

The stack trace if SCRIPT28 is available  -

```
module.exports = TO_STRING_TAG_SUPPORT ? classofRaw : function (it) {
  var O, tag, result;
  return it === undefined ? 'Undefined' : it === null ? 'Null' // @@toStringTag case
  : typeof (tag = tryGet(O = Object(it), TO_STRING_TAG)) == 'string' ? tag // builtinTag case
  : CORRECT_ARGUMENTS ? classofRaw(O) // ES3 arguments fallback
  : (result = classofRaw(O)) == 'Object' && typeof O.callee == 'function' ? 'Arguments' : result;
};

/***/ }),

/***/ "./node_modules/react-app-polyfill/node_modules/core-js/internals/collection-add-all.js":
/*!**********************************************************************************************!*\
  !*** ./node_modules/react-app-polyfill/node_modules/core-js/internals/collection-add-all.js ***!
  \**********************************************************************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
```

I have made sure that react-app-polyfill imports are the top level imports, before React-dom and React.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume that you had installed the polyfills and referenced it properly. After that try to go to the node_modules folder in your project and try to delete the .cache folder. Then again try to run the app. It should work in the IE browser.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I have already done that. Polyfills are being read as the app is not throwing a syntax error anymore, it's throwing a stackoverflow error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55967048/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by using an es6 polyfill cdn from [Polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io/v3/) instead of react-app-polyfill. I removed react-app-polyfill and added the cdn script in index.html

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=default,es6"></script>
```

Now my app works on IE11 and it does not throw stackoverflow error.

EDIT:: polyfill v3  is out so that is recommended over v2 -

```
 <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default,es6"></script>
```