# Blank screen while running React in microsoft edge and firefox browsers

Tags: reactjs, firefox, microsoft-edge

Blank screen is displayed and debugging in console it says
SCRIPT1028: SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number

my package.json file is

```
{
  "name": "sample react app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.6.0",
    "@hapi/joi": "^15.1.1",
    "@svgr/webpack": "4.3.2",
    "@trainline/react-skeletor": "^1.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.4",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.0.2",
    "camelcase": "^5.2.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "css-loader": "2.1.1",
    "dotenv": "6.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.0.2",
    "eslint-loader": "3.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "3.13.0",
    "file-loader": "3.0.1",
    "fs-extra": "7.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.5",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.20.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "is-wsl": "^1.1.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "0.1.0",
    "jest-resolve": "24.9.0",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.4.0",
    "locale-codes": "^1.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.8.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
    "paginator": "^1.0.0",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.5.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-normalize": "7.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "query-string": "^6.9.0",
    "radium": "^0.26.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.4",
    "react-color": "^2.17.3",
    "react-content-loader": "^4.3.4",
    "react-dates": "^21.5.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^9.1.0",
    "react-dnd": "^10.0.2",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^10.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-image-crop": "^8.4.2",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^5.0.4",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^1.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "reactstrap": "^8.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "resolve": "1.12.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "3.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "7.2.0",
    "semver": "6.3.0",
    "style-loader": "1.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.4.1",
    "ts-pnp": "1.1.4",
    "url-loader": "2.1.0",
    "webpack": "4.41.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.2.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "4.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ],
    "watchPlugins": [
      "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
      "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "env": {
      "production": {
        "plugins": [
          [
            "react-remove-properties",
            {
              "properties": [
                "data-test"
              ]
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-react-remove-properties": "^0.3.0",
    "check-prop-types": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
    "moxios": "^0.4.0",
    "sinon": "^7.5.0"
  }
}
```

wanted to know any of the library creating the issue or any configurations missing?
FYI,code is runnning perfectly in chrome and safari browsers.
Anything to be added in package.json file

Comment: It is related to polyfill I assume. Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53631949/why-ie-11-display-blank-page-rendering-react-app

Comment: Yes.But did'nt work

Comment: I tried to create a new react app and I am able to run it in MS Edge 44 browser. You are using many dependencies. It can be possible that some dependencies you are using are outdated or not supported in Edge. You need to check and verify each of it to find the cause for the issue. Also, check the console to see whether it shows any error or warning message.