# IE11 displays a blank page on localhost, all other browsers work

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, next.js

I have a web-based project. I build it. The port used is 8080.

In chrome, safari, firefox, the project works fine. No errors in the console.
However, on internet explorer 11, the page is blank, but the icon is loaded, as is the HTML, which I can see in the page source.
The page looks like this:
[image: Image of the blank page]

The errors in the developer tools of IE11 outputs this:
[image: Image of the developer tools in IE11]

I see a compiler error for some missing semi-colons. However, the error is on line 100,000, which makes me think it is in the compiled file. This error is not in other browsers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why IE 11 display blank page rendering react app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53631949/why-ie-11-display-blank-page-rendering-react-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be related to some JS syntax issues. If bundle includes some modern features of JS, it is supported by modern browsers, but not but IE. So IE cannot parse it correctly.
You can open the error in sources to check if there is some modern syntax construction.
In case this is the problem, you need to setup transpiler options to support IE. Most likely it's babel settings/browserlist.

Comment: This is correct and it caused the blank page. I found the error in the js-file, which is some library, that IE11 can't handle. I need to transpile my node_modules.

Answer (score 1):

This article will guide you to resolve the issue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/browsers/cannot-access-websites

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/ie-11-doesnt-preload-while-preloading-with-500/e5d8611d-1a6f-4d2d-beba-4cbb214bd99e

May be you need to change the permissions in IE 11 if the site is not secure

https://www.support.com/how-to/how-to-fix-site-is-not-secure-in-internet-explorer-12900

Comment: Thank you Jaspal. The site is http when accessing localhost. However, I don't believe any of this is the cause of the issue. If it was a security issue, the site would be fully blocked. but the icon is loaded, and the code is "there". 

I've gone through your links and the steps therein.