# console.log() above import statements in root file does not execute before import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

Consider the root index.js file in a React app that does the following:

```
console.log("INDEX.JS")
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
//Internal Dependencies
import Auth from './containers/Auth';
import store from './store/store';
import ErrorBoundary from './containers/ErrorBoundary';
//Highcharts config
import highchartsConfig from './globalChartConfig';
//Global styles
import './index.css';

highchartsConfig();

render(
  <Router>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <Auth />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    </Provider>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The import statements are executed BEFORE the `console.log` statement at the top of this file. a console.log at the top of the `Auth.js` file will be executed first. Why is that?

The following `console.log()` is the first thing that logs to the console.

```
// Auth.js
console.log('AUTH')
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
```

Comment: Are you using TypeScript or ECMAScript imports?

Comment: No typescript is being used. I'm using ECMAScript imports

Comment: The real question is, why does it matter? If your code depends on the execution of `console.log`, you've got bigger problems ;). For the order, `import` is synchronous; see [What is the defined execution order of ES6 imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35551366/215552)

Comment: No I was simply curious, it's not causing any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must scope all `import` statements at the top. This restriction allows `webpack`(not only webpack, any module loader actually) to analyze statically what modules are imported by a module and load them before executing its body.

```
console.log('first import then log')
import { foo } from 'foo'
```

Putting code above `import` throws an `eslint` warning (import/first)

> Why inside `index.js` `console.log` fires after the imports and inside
>   `auth.js` executes in the expected order?

When calling `index.js` (entry point which will render the entire application) webpack will bundle every module including those required for `App` and `Auth` and then call `console.log`. When you access `Auth.js` all modules are already bundled so the only thing left to do is to call `console.log`.

[For a detailed explanation](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html)

Comment: Then why is it that in AUTH.js my import statement at the very top of ITS import statement are executed at the expected time?

Comment: Can you update the question with the revelant code for `auth.js`?

Comment: No, as you can see above. Index.js renders Auth. And Auth (upon passing conditions) renders the rest of the application

Comment: I inverted the order hahaha. Updating the answer